# Using Lucene's tokens in NLP library for POS tagging

Tags: solr, lucene, nlp, opennlp

I am getting my feet wet with Solr and NLP. I have asked in an another question how is it possible to store all nouns in the Solr. But now, I am realizing that would be step two. First question to solve is, Lucene already has tokenizer. And while doing POS tagging, we have to do the tokenization first. Is it possible to use the Lucene's tokens in the Morph Adorner (or Open NLP) to generate POS tags ? If so, question comes, how can I store those POS tags in solr index ?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780569/use-lucune-to-store-part-of-speech-semantic-role-lemma-ner-mentioning-and-ot/19797310#19797310

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use a different tokenizer in OpenNLP - the API documentation for OpenNLP shows how to do that pretty straightforwardly. However, your bigger problem is that the tokenization you use to tag POS needs to be the same tokenization you use to train your POS tagger, and that means you can't use the prebuilt OpenNLP POS models. Finally, Lucene's tokenizer may be a different sort of tokenizer - it may make different assumptions (because it's targeted for information reetrieval) than the ones you'd want for language understanding.

Comment: in short, using Lucene's tokenized text in nlp library won't be a good idea ?

Comment: In short, yes. Plus a sentence because Stack hates short comments.